# Mixing own XML with HTML5 havin eclipse to display code hints

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, mixing, hint

I am writing my own templating engine mainly for web applications.

It is actually mix of my own XML tags and HTML.

Here is the sample:

```
<lp:view xmlns:lp="http://sminit.com/view" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://sminit.com/view view.xsd ">
    <lp:list name="my_items">

        <lp:list_header>

            <table>

        </lp:list_header>

        <lp:list_item>

              <tr><td>$title$</td></tr>

        </lp:list_item>

        <lp:list_footer>
                </table>
        </lp:list_footer>

    </lp:list>
</lp:view>
```

A little explanation:
Those tags prefixed with "lp" belong to my templating engine and are kind of "processing instructions" for it. The lp:view is a root node, then there is a lp:list node which having received some data source will produce a list: first it will include content of lp:list_header, then repeat proper times content of lp:list_item (replacing $title$ by actual data, but this does not matter here), then it will add content of lp:list_footer node. As you can see, for this reason I have html tag "table" splitting across my tags.

I have met two major problems here:
1. Eclipse complains that "table" is not properly closed -- I want Eclipse to stop complaining, treat this tag as a text or -- maybe you can suggest something?
2. Eclipse will not show any code hint if I am inside any of html tags. (code hint: attributes that maybe used by this tag like "class" or "id" etc)

I understand that I'm asking a weird freak question, but maybe there are some XSD gurus here who can direct me: 
Eclipse should treat my xml template file as the following:
1. the tags prefixed "lp" are gods! They have precedence over anything other. Only errors from that tags (missing required attributes, missing required child elements etc) should be displayed.
2. All the other tags (any stuff in between angle brackets) are HTML tags. Eclipse should display code hint for them, but should anything be "incorrect" (like in my sample: no closing /table tag) -- Eclipse should not complain.

I hope this is possible.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap your HTML in `CDATA` blocks. This will make the XML parser consider the contents (the unclosed `<table>`) to be plain text, and not a broken tag.

```
    <lp:list_header><![CDATA[

        <table>

    ]]></lp:list_header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a partial answer, but I'll still put it as an answer because it's too long to type into a comment.

To stop Eclipse complaining about unclosed tags, you should wrap the content in a `<![CDATA[..]]` section like so:

```
<lp:view xmlns:lp="http://sminit.com/view" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sminit.com/view view.xsd ">
  <lp:list name="my_items">

    <lp:list_header>

        <![CDATA[ <table> ]]>

    </lp:list_header>

    <lp:list_item>

          <tr><td>$title$</td></tr>

    </lp:list_item>

    <lp:list_footer>
            <![CDATA[ </table> ]]>
    </lp:list_footer>

</lp:list>
```

They will be treated as text and Eclipse will not complain, but in that case you will lose any Eclipse completion inside the CDATA section.

To get completion working for HTML tags, I think you can try adding a default namespace for XHTML to your root tag, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<lp:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lp="http://sminit.com/view" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sminit.com/view view.xsd ">
  <lp:list name="my_items">

    <lp:list_header>

        <![CDATA[ <table> ]]>

    </lp:list_header>

    <lp:list_item>

          <tr><td>$title$</td></tr>

    </lp:list_item>

    <lp:list_footer>
            <![CDATA[ </table> ]]>
    </lp:list_footer>

</lp:list>
```

EDIT: I think the second part won't work though, because the XHTML schema defines that the root element should be `<html>`. I just tried in Eclipse and completion for HTML tags only starts working when I first insert an `<html>` tag somewhere in the document. Maybe some other people can weigh in.